# json.loads() failing

Tags: python, json, celery

So I'm working on a django project which uses a celery task queue to make HTTP requests.

In my celery task code I have:

```
json.loads('{"content-type": "application/json"}')
print test.headers
json.loads(test.headers)
```

Which results in:

```
[2012-07-19 17:02:38,536: WARNING/PoolWorker-4] '{"content-type": "application/json"}'
[2012-07-19 17:02:38,569: ERROR/MainProcess] Task core.tasks.test_run[f304bcdd-72b3-4dd5-9abb-927dc29e7f65] raised exception: ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/task/trace.py", line 212, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)     
  File "/opt/ironman_deploy/Ironman/core/tasks.py", line 18, in test_run
    json.loads(test.headers)
  File "/usr/local/bin/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/bin/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/bin/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
No JSON object could be decoded: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I have literally no idea what's going on... clearly json can decode the string, because it doesn't fail 2 lines above, however when I pass the string in by reference it seems to choke.

Could anyone shed light on this for me?

Answer (score 1):

test.headers could be a dict. If you print it, it will output something looking like JSON, yet test.headers might not be JSON at all, and decoding it would cause JSON to choke.

Comment: I've run `print type(test.headers)` and got `<type 'str'>`

Comment: Okay. So check explicitly whether test.headers is equal to '{"content-type": "application/json"}'. If the log tells you the truth, it should be. And then if it is, it's some weird bug whereby the same string may be loaded or not depending on where it's stored. If it's not, and I'm betting it's not, there must be some wee gremlin hidden in the test.headers version -- something invisible when printed. Dunno: once I got a 0xA0 character that looked like a space (I lost an evening tracking that one down!), and weirder things are known to exist.

Comment: +1 for gremlins. Compare `ord(x) for x in test.headers` against `ord(x) for x in '{"content-type": "application/json"}'` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Whats is "test.headers" your snippet doesn't indicate this. If test.headers is being assigned to the result of the first json.loads call, then the second one will obviosuly fail since you aren't providing it a string. The second call should be json.dumps(test.headers)

Comment: The output of `print test.headers` is shown in the first line of the second code snippet, in the celery command line:
`[2012-07-19 17:02:38,536: WARNING/PoolWorker-4] '{"content-type": "application/json"}'
`

Comment: Does `test.headers` include the text `[2012-07-19 17:02:38,536: WARNING/Poolworder-4]` ?  Because if so, the JSON decoder will not be happy.